# Javascript - Volume control for a video

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make a volume control slider for a video. so far i have linked everything correctly and put in the js code. The slider is set to 50 (50%) when the window loads and then has an event listener for if the slider changes.

Here is the function that controls the volume.

```
function VolumeControl()
{
    var VolumeLevel = Video.volume * (Volume.value / 100);
    Video.volume = VolumeLevel;
}
```

It only seems to work when i decrease the slider. the volume will go down and stay there. then when it drag it up to full it stays the same, and when i drag it down again, it decreases. i think i just have the formula wrong, any help?

Comment: the "Volume" refers to the slider varible btw

Comment: What are the valid values for `Video.volume`. 0 to 100?

Comment: actually no its  0 - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this would be the correct handler:

```
function VolumeControl() {
    Video.volume = Volume.value;
}
```

...if you configure the volume slider correctly.

Comment: the volume.value is 0-100 so i just made it  Video.volume = (Volume.value / 100); instead and it worked. seems so obvious now lol thanks